# InvalidOperationException when trying to get services from remote server

Tags: vb.net, exception, invalidoperationexception, windows-server-2012-r2

I am facing a strange error. I check from server A on server B if a specific service is running.

Code sample:

```
        Try
        Dim services() As ServiceController = ServiceController.GetServices(server)
        For Each service In services
            If service.ServiceName = serviceName Then
                If service.Status = ServiceProcess.ServiceControllerStatus.Running Then
                    write_log("Service is running on: " & server)
                    Return True
                Else
                    Return False
                End If
            End If
        Next

    Catch ex As Exception
        write_log("ERROR on getService request")
        write_log(ex.ToString)
    End Try
```

Most times the request is successful. But sometimes I get an error.
Stack trace:

```
5316    2015-02-21 07:24:47 System.InvalidOperationException: Cannot open Service Control Manager on computer 'XXXXX'. This operation might require other privileges. ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The RPC server is unavailable
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController.GetDataBaseHandleWithAccess(String machineName, Int32 serviceControlManaqerAccess)
   at System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController.GetServicesOfType(String machineName, Int32 serviceType)
   at K2SystemInfo.K2SystemInfo.CheckIfServiceIsRunning(String serviceName, String server)
```

With a retry immediately after the error I can get the service information. The service that starts my programm is admin on both server.

Why does ServiceController.GetServices(server) sometimes fail. Although it is mostly working fine?

The problem occurs only on Windows Server 2012 R2 servers. On Windows Server 2008 R2 it works fine.